# Set Base SDK greater than latest iOS compatible with Xcode version

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, compatibility, base-sdk

I have OS 10.10.5. I cannot update to El Capitan due to some incompatibily with an hardware I use, and I cannot update Xcode to 7.3.1 because it is only compatible with El Capitsn

So the Base SDK available in my Xcode version is 9.2, but I want to set it to 9.3.2.

When i try to run my app on a device with iOS 9.3.2, Xcode says "Could not find developer disk image.

Is it possible to set it manually?

Comment: The only way to use an iOS 9.3.x device is to use Xcode 7.3.x. You are stuck until you can upgrade OS X.

Comment: so if I send the app like this to App Store, the only devices that will be able do download will be the ones with iOS <= 9.2?

Comment: I didn't say that. An app built with a Base SDK of iOS 2.0 will run on a device with iOS 10. That's not the issue. Your issue is with Xcode.

Comment: thanks! so the only problem is that I can't test it on devices with iOS > 9.2

Comment: You can't test on newer devices and you can't use newer APIs than the Base SDK.